# Ensures() - guideline support library

Tags: c++, c++11, cpp-core-guidelines, guideline-support-library

I am trying to understand how to use `Ensures()` in code. As given in the [example](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#i8-prefer-ensures-for-expressing-postconditions), if I tried using `Ensures()` as follows...

```
int main(void)
{
    int result = 0;
    // Some calculation
    Ensures(result == 255);
    return 0;
}
```

If the `result` variable is not equal to `255`, the program crashes with the following output `"terminate called without an active exception"`. My question is how to use `Ensures()` properly?

Comment: If you `std::terminate` is called in your example, then it works as is should.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Are you using the [Microsoft GSL implementation](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL)? Then if you check [the `gsl_assert.h` header file](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/gsl/gsl_assert) you will see that if `GSL_TERMINATE_ON_CONTRACT_VIOLATION` is defined (which is default) then `Ensures` will call [`std::terminate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate) which will give you the error you get.

If you want an exception to be thrown (with file and line-number information) then you need to define `GSL_THROW_ON_CONTRACT_VIOLATION` before including the GSL.

As for if you're using `Ensures` properly, then yes you are.

---

### Updates on 2021

`GSL_TERMINATE_ON_CONTRACT_VIOLATION` is removed, always calling `terminate()`.

Comment: Thanks, for the reply, will check the header.

Comment: I am not using MS GSL. I tried using MS GSL with Visual Studio 2013. But was getting "fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler".

Comment: As per your suggestion, I went into the "gsl-lite.h" and modified the # define gsl_CONFIG_THROWS_FOR_TESTING  0 to # define gsl_CONFIG_THROWS_FOR_TESTING  1. Now I am getting exception which i can catch it. Thanks.

Comment: As decided by the Core Guideline authors the MS GSL lately removed `GSL_THROW_ON_CONTRACT_VIOLATION` and now always `std::terminate`s. But... there is still a discussion ongoing because the Core Guidelines seem to be inconsistent about the behaviour of `Expects`.