# Advantage of gsl assert vs assert in c++?

Tags: c++, guideline-support-library

I know the use of `assert` in C++. Wanted to know is there any difference between and any benefit(I think `assert` is costlier according as mentioned in https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/7-12a-assert-and-static_assert/ so performance wise, are both same?) in using `gsl_assert` over `assert`? Why `gsl_assert` was added in gsl library since there is already `assert` support in c++(even though `assert` came from 'C', since we add `#include<cassert>` for using `assert` in C++)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gsl/gsl_assert>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int val;
    cin >> val;
    Ensures( val > 5 );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36349523/ensures-guideline-support-library) question.

Comment: I got it, thanks for sharing:)

Comment: but I wanted to know about the performance comparison of both, since assert is generally not used in the production build as mentioned in the above link(learncpp).

Comment: Off-topic, but [`using namespace std;` is considered bad practice.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a question of performance; it's a question of flexibility.

#### C assert

This just terminates (in debug builds) if the condition is true, and usually does nothing in release builds.

#### GSL contract check

[Depending on configuration](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/gsl/gsl_assert), this can:

1. Throw an exception
2. Terminate
3. Do nothing

   - …except signal to the optimiser that we expect the condition to hold (if supported)

---

In some configuration modes, I suppose GSL's `Expects` and `Ensures` macros end up doing pretty much the same thing as `assert`. But not in all.

It's worth noting, though, that the GSL behaviour appears not to be dependent on build configuration (debug vs release). I guess (and I am only guessing) that, for performance-critical code, a sensible project maintainer would choose mode #1 or #2 in debug builds, and #3 (or possibly #2) in release builds.

Comment: As decided by the Core Guideline authors the MS GSL lately removed `GSL_THROW_ON_CONTRACT_VIOLATION` and now always `std::terminate`s. But... there is still a discussion ongoing because the Core Guidelines seem to be inconsistent about the behaviour of `Expects`.